# After rooting with Kingo Root, do I need to leave Kingo Link on the device?

Tags: rooting, kingo

I successfully rooted an Azpen 746G using Kingo Root on a PC.  It placed an app on the tablet called Kingo Link.  Once the rooting process is complete, can I delete this app off the tablet?

Because the word "link" is so common, googling for this was not helpful

Comment: @Organc - check out Google Search [documentation](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433#0) and [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)... many of the tips can be especially handy to coders & techies as *so many* keywords have multiple definitions, and the coding definition is rarely the most common. ;-) In this case you could have searched for [`"kingo root" "kingo link" need`](https://www.google.com/search?q="kingo+root"+"kingo+link"+need). (incidentally - this question is the top hit for that search!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are safe to uninstall it, the root is done, you dont even have to connect it to PC anymore. In case you do need to root again, connecting the pc will auto-install it back anyway (nless you uncheck the almost invisible "install recomended apk" or something, that shows below inside kingoroot pc software window! lol) Cheers